# showing extra data in array values

Tags: c, arrays, char, symbian, carbide

I am using this part of c code in carbide c/c++

```
   char c1[]={0x01};
   char c2[]={0x02};
   char*  c [] = {c1,c2};
```

when i check values of c[0],c[1].. i am seeing two values like this in debug mode

```
c[0] = \x01\x01 & (x) = *[0] = \x01  
c[1] = \x02\x01\x01 & (x) = *[1] = \x02
```

and if i calculate length like this

```
int cclen2 = strlen(c[0]);
```

getting cclen2 = 2; but i should get values as 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`c1` and `c2` do not have null terminators, and `strlen()` requires a null terminator (along with many other C string handling functions, like `printf("%s", c1)` for example). A null terminator is only implicitly added when a string literal is used to initialise the `char[]`.

Change to either:

```
char c1[] = { 0x01, 0x00 };
char c2[] = { 0x02, 0x00 };
```

or:

```
char c1[] = "\x01";
char c2[] = "\x02";
```

Answer (score 1):

Array creates a special type of constant pointer. if you declare this as char then at last a null character is added.
actually your c[0] statement is replaced by *(c+0); and get the address c.

strlen(c[0]) is replaced by strlen(c);
and you got full length of string till null character.

i think this is enough explanation.